# How does adb shell getprop and setprop work?

Tags: android, adb, getproperty

I would like to understand how `adb shell setprop mypropertykey mypropertyvalue` works. In other words, I edited the `/system/build.prop` file, but when I try to use `getprop` command to read the value back I seem to be getting a blank value instead.

However, when I set the property via `adb shell setprop` in the root mode and then unroot the emulator and read the value using code, I am able to get the proper value.

What I don't understand is, if the value is set via `adb shell setprop` then why does it not get written to the `build.prop` file? Then where does `getprop` read the values from?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Android system properties are being managed by special `property_service`. The `/system/build.prop` is just one out of 4-6 (depending on the version) read-only files containing the default values that `property_service` uses to populate its internal in-memory database with during start-up. So changes to the files during run time would not propagate until after reboot.

The `setprop` and `getprop` commands are used to access the data in that database. Unless the property name starts with `persist.` - then the value gets stored in `/data/property` folder.

Comment: so if there is an embedded application that has to read from a build.prop file, that value would always be available to it since the device would hve been rebooted already?

Comment: So, if I'll add `.property` prefix for my `log.tag.CrashlyticsCore` variable. Will it becomes persistent?